# how to turn value of createTextNode() to a link?

Tags: javascript, filter

I have a filter method that returns an array's keys and values. Right now I am getting the full url but I need it wrapped in  tag so I can pass the url to its href. The filter method:

```
let filtered = myData.map(row => 
Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(row).filter(it => { 
    let key = it[0]; 
    return ['Carat','Clarity','Shape', 'Color', 'Cut','Symmetry','Report', 'view' ].indexOf(key) >= 0 
    })
  )
);
```

view's value which is the last element in return statement gives a url. when I do the following to generate my table I get keys and values but how do I select that view (which is a link) and wrap it in a  tag and place view in href?

```
 function generateTableHead(table, data) {
      let thead = table.createTHead();
      let row = thead.insertRow();

      for (let key of data) {
        let th = document.createElement("th");
        let text = document.createTextNode(key);
      // casual formalities 
        th.appendChild(text);
        row.appendChild(th);
      }
    }

    function generateTable(table, data) {
      for (let element of data) {
        let row = table.insertRow();
        for (key in element) {
          let cell = row.insertCell();
          let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
          cell.appendChild(text);
        }
      }
    }


let table = document.querySelector("table");

    // create a variable from values
    generateTable(table, filtered);

    // create variable from keys
    generateTableHead(table, headArr);
```

Comment: `document.createElement("a");` ?

Comment: How do I target that element of array: view in above filter

Answer (score 0):

take the value in JS and use innerHTML to set an html element to a template literal of the href element...

for example

```
//JS
let link = "https://yoururl.com/path/thingy";

let targetElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");

targetElement.innerHTML = `<a href=${link}>thingy</a>`;
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have link defined like you did. My link is coming from view in the following line: return ['Carat','Clarity','Shape', 'Color', 'Cut','Symmetry','Report', 'view' ].indexOf(key) >= 0; now accessing that view (link) while the table is being generated is the mystery. The item doesn't have an id