# Turn html table data to run in a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a table generated with Javascript that output some JSON data. Now I know I should probably not repeat myself so much but one of the element of this array needs to be wrapped in a link, and I don't know how to write a loop that output all members but the also member with some styling. Is there a way to do this in a loop, while keeping the format of output as this code gives? 
The table head part is already taken care of, the tbody is where I have problem: As you the last element didn't fit in a loop exactly. referring to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020271/how-to-turn-value-of-createtextnode-to-a-link/58020320?noredirect=1#comment102444341_58020320) where I had it in a loop.

```
for (let j= 0; j< filtered.length; j++){
  var row = table.insertRow(1); 
  row.classList.add("headRow")
  var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell0.innerHTML = filtered[j].Carat;
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = filtered[j].Color;
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell2.innerHTML = filtered[j].Shape;
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell3.innerHTML = filtered[j].Cut;
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
  cell4.innerHTML = filtered[j].Symmetry;
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
  cell5.innerHTML = filtered[j].Report;
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
  cell6.innerHTML = filtered[j].Clarity;
  var cell7 = row.insertCell(7);
  cell7.innerHTML = filtered[j].Polish;
  var cell8 = row.insertCell(8);
  cell8.innerHTML =  '<a href="' + filtered[j].link_view + '"> View</a>' ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to create a configuration object containing the attribute that will be displayed at each row and a renderer function that will be used to determine how the data is going to be displayed.

Following is a quick example:

```
var renderer = {
    text: function(data) {
        return data;
    },
    link: function(data) {
        return '<a href="' + data + '">View</a>';
    }
};

var config = [
    {attr: "Carat", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Color", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Shape", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Cut", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Symmetry", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Report", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Clarity", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Polish", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "link_view", renderer: renderer.link}
];

filtered.forEach(function(data) {

    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    config.forEach(function(entry) {

        var cell = document.createElement("td"),
            value = data[entry.attr];

        cell.innerHTML = entry.renderer(value);

        row.appendChild(cell);

    });

    table.appendChild(row);

});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, this is amazing I should educate myself about config object. Thank you @Romulo

Answer (score 2):

Use an array of `Carat`, `Color` property names as strings, and loop over them to extract them from the object and create cells:

```
const props = ['Carat', 'Color', 'Shape']; // ...
for (let j= 0; j< filtered.length; j++){
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  row.classList.add("headRow");
  props.forEach((prop) => {
    const cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.innerHTML = filtered[i][prop];
  });
  var cell8 = row.insertCell();
  cell8.innerHTML =  '<a href="' + filtered[j].link_view + '"> View</a>' ;
}
```

Note that unless the object values are composed of HTML markup, you should use `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`. (`textContent` is both faster and safer)

You don't have to specify an index when calling `insertCell` because you're inserting the cells [in order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell):

> index is the cell index of the new cell. **If index is -1 or equal to the number of cells, the cell is appended as the last cell in the row**. If index is greater than the number of cells, an IndexSizeError exception will result. **If index is omitted it defaults to -1**.

If `filtered` is an array, you can remove the need for ugly manual iteration by using `forEach` instead, if you wish:

```
const props = ['Carat', 'Color', 'Shape']; // ...
filtered.forEach((obj) => {
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  row.classList.add("headRow");
  props.forEach((prop) => {
    const cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.innerHTML = obj[prop];
  });
  var cell8 = row.insertCell();
  cell8.innerHTML =  '<a href="' + obj.link_view + '"> View</a>' ;
});
```

Comment: Thanks but how do add the element cell8 = row.insertCell(8); in a link tag?

Comment: Because it's an `<a>` rather than just text, it won't work in the loop - just add it manually afterwards.

Comment: Is the `link_view` property you're using predictably trustworthy (like from a database or API), or can it come from user input? If from user input, better to insert it by assigning to the `href` of the `<a>`, otherwise you'll be permitting arbitrary code execution

Comment: doesn't prop already include obj.link_view? this way I get two column of link_view. How I am excluding link_view from forEach?

Comment: Just don't put it into the array when defining `props` - the `props` array should contain only properties you want to iterate over in the inner loop

Comment: It comes from a sql query stored in php encode and filtered by javascirpt func and now is called filtered, is an object that contains all keys and values and one these values "link_view" is  a url, so I want to wrap it in a a tag but the rest are just numbers to show without any styling

Comment: If it comes from a trustworthy source, then it's safe to concatenate directly into the HTML string like that.

Comment: I am sorry when you say like that, you mean your solution or the way I wrote it?

Comment: Both your way of putting in the `href` and mine are exactly the same (concatenating an HTML string), and if the `obj.link_view` is trustworthy, then there's no need to change it

Comment: The only issue here is a way to use your loop and still edit the last element, I can not access obj.link_view right now I am not in a loop so it wouldn't list all its value